# Resize divs when maximum divs are created

Tags: javascript

See the diagram below - [image: Main Container]

On click i create a div of `width 680px` and `height 295px` in the top left corner of the screen and go on until the bottom left corner of the screen with javascript. like image below...
[image]

Now when the 4th div is created, On the 5th click, i want my application to be able to calculate the space available and if there is no space available it creates a second div next to the first div created and so on in all other divs as seen in image...
[image]

Does anyone know how to calculate the space available dynamically everytime a div is created and then accordingly create smaller divs to fit into the spaces in the main container?

Comment: Is your container fixed 1360 x 590? When clicked 5 times, what happens to the top left div? Is it split in quarters with the bottom half empty or is it split in half? Also, what happens after the 19th click? Does it stop or it creates a quarter of the "when clicked once div"?

Comment: SO the main container remains fixed. when clicked the 5th time, the top left div width and height is devided by 2 and is resized to fit a smaller div next to it like how the 3rd figure shows.. 19 clicks will result in smaller divs created continously 19 times so it will keep resizing to fit smaller divs.. so once 4 divs are created in the original position of top left div, it moves on to the top right div and subdivides.